# Picture uploading proble

Tags: php, html

I don't have an idea why it doesn't upload pictures(But the same peace of code does). Please help me.
HTML:

```
$max_filesize = 524288;
$upload_path = './img/';
$id=$_POST["id"];

for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
{
    (string)$inside="inside".$i;
    echo $inside;
    $filename = $_FILES[$inside]['name'];
    echo $filename;
    $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);
    echo $ext;

    if (isset($_POST[$inside])){

        if(filesize($_FILES[$inside]['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
            die('File is too big.');

        if(!is_writable($upload_path))
            die('Cannot access folder - 777.');

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$inside]['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $id . "inside" . $i . $ext))
        {
            echo 'Uploaded successfuly ';
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo '<img src="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" width="300" >';
        } else {
            echo 'Something went wrong, try again.';
        }
    }
}
```

Before that:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""/>
    Що в коробці(Фото): <p>
    <input type="file" name="inside1"
          accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"> <p>
    <input type="file" name="inside2"
          accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"> <p>
    <input type="file" name="inside3"
          accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"> <p>
</form>
```

It says 'Something went wrong, try again.'.

Comment: You should [edit] your post, explain the code and provide what the function `move_uploaded_file` does!

Comment: Ok, i see a problem. I don't use corretly names of files.

Comment: @hc_dev https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I am not speaking PHP  Thank you for your help. Seems this also helped the OP.

Comment: @J.Doe So is your question still open? Or have you found the issue and will probably answer it yourself 

Answer (score 0):

Strange form - `<form></form>`

```
 <form action="<?php echo'admin/photo_upload.php'; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size; ?>" /> 

            <p><input name="file_upload[]" type="file" id="file_upload[]" value=""></p>

            <p><input name="file_upload[]" type="file" id="file_upload[]" value=""></p>

            <p>Caption: <input type="text" name="caption" value="" /></p>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
```